# how to handle images in different resolutions for windows phone 8.1 WinRT?

Tags: image, windows-runtime, windows-phone-8.1

how to handle images in different resolutions for windows phone 8.1 WinRT?

On Android, you create different folders with images to be used in different resolutions.
In iOS you use @2x and @3x to handle different images.

How do you manage images for different resolutions on Windows Phone 8.1 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can provide different images with the same base name plus a scale-XXX suffix for the percentage of magnification. For example: logo.scale-100.png . If you support many you can place the images in directories named for the qualifiers.

The same system can be used for localization and for high contrast images.

See [How to name resources using qualifiers](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/Hh965324(v=win.10).aspx) for details